# Vimeo CallBack function - Click the button when the video ends

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I have bunch of videos which I am working on. Currently, users have to click the "button" to make sure that they have watched the video before moving on to next one. I want to change this feature so whenever a user watches videos the "button" automatically clicks and next video uploads. Clicking of button is something important in order to save the user data.

For now this is what I have implemented(Test Code):

```
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/156873237?title=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>

<button type="button" onclick= "showMsg();">Click Me!</button>  
<script>
     function showMsg(){
           alert('you clicked');
     }
</script>

<script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$(function() { 
    var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
    player = $f(iframe);
    player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
  });

 $('button').bind('click', function() {
      player.api($(this).onFinish());
   });

 function onFinish() {
        alert('finished');
      }
 });
```

Using this, whenever the video ends it does not give any response. Is there anything I am missing or doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their document [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api), you should add more parameter on the embed url **api=1&player_id=player1** which is enabling the API and indicate the playerId

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><iframe id="player1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/156873237?title=0&api=1&player_id=player1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></p>

<button type="button" onclick= "showMsg();">Click Me!</button>


<script>
    function showMsg(){
        alert('you clicked');
    }

    $(function() { 
        var iframe = $('#player1')[0];
        player = $f(iframe);
        player.addEvent('ready', function() {       
            player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
        });

     function onFinish(id) {
            alert('finished');
          }
     });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vy9kf0w5/49/